# Why does SFML load a white square instead of a texture?

Tags: c++, sfml

I am working on a class which manages the loading of  multiple textures. Before I've done that everything worked fine, but when I use my brand-new class, only a white square appears on the screen:

```
namespace Textures {
    enum ID { Landscape, Airplane, Missile };
}

class ATextureHolder {
public:
    void                Load(Textures::ID id, const std::string& filename);
    sf::Texture&        Get(Textures::ID);
private:
    std::map<Textures::ID, std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture>> texture_map;

};

void
ATextureHolder::Load(Textures::ID id, const std::string& filename) {
    std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture> texture( new sf::Texture() );
    texture->loadFromFile(filename.c_str());

    this->texture_map.insert(std::make_pair(id, std::move(texture)));
}

sf::Texture&
ATextureHolder::Get(Textures::ID id) {
    auto found = this->texture_map.find(id);
    return *found->second;
}

AGame::AGame():
    window( sf::VideoMode( 640, 480 ), "SFML Game" ),
    player(), //player is an instance of sf::Sprite class
    player_speed( 100.0 ),
    time_per_frame( sf::seconds( 1.0 / 60.0 ) ) {

        ATextureHolder textures;
        textures.Load(Textures::Airplane, "Media/Textures/plane.png");
        this->player.setTexture(textures.Get(Textures::Airplane));
        this->player.setPosition(100.0, 100.0);
}
```

The idea is to bind texture names stored in `enum ID` with unique pointers, which in their turn point to actual `sf::Texture` objects. So the class makes a binding in the `Load()` method and the `Get` method should return a reference to these texture objects. But something goes wrong and I have no idea what is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just guessing here, but... In the `AGame` constructor, the `textures` variable is a *local* variable which goes out of scope and is destructed once the constructor returns. This destruction of `textures` or course means that the map it contains is also destructed, and with it the `unique_ptr` objects, leading to the reference returned by `ATextureHolder::Get` to become invalid.

Unless the `this->player.setTexture` takes its argument by value and does a deep copy, then the texture will be invalid and any use of the object will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Looks like you were right. My mistake seems so dumb in retrospect. Thank you a lot!